# I am using too many if statements

Tags: c#, mysql, object, dynamic

I have written a bit of C# but I'm convinced that these 17 if statements could be reduced. I have tried a lot but so far nothing worked for me. Its an Windows form app for the once who want to know.

```
MySqlCommand cmdcount = new MySqlCommand("Select count(vak_id) from bezet", conn);
        var counter = cmdcount.ExecuteScalar();
        int count = 0;
        count = Convert.ToInt32(counter);

        while(count > 0)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmdklant = new MySqlCommand("Select klant_id from bezet where vak_id = @id", conn);
            cmdklant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", count);
            var spotinfo = cmdcount.ExecuteScalar();
            string infospot = Convert.ToString(spotinfo);

            if (infospot == "")
            {
                if (count == 8)
                {
                    P8.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else if(count == 7)
                {
                    P7.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else if (count == 6)
                {
                    P6.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                //etc...
            }
            else
            {
                //the same but then color.red
            }
            count--;
        }
```

Comment: This works in the way it is now for the once who doubt it.

Comment: I would probably create a List<Color> and use an index into it. If it isn't working the UI probably has no time to display the changes. A Refresh might help..

Comment: Or a `Dictionary<int, Color>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you load a counter, then for each associated "P" you set color based on some other condition

How about putting those "P" things into an array:

```
int count = ...
new [] { P1, P2, P3, P4 .. P8 }
.Take(count)
.Select((p, idx) => new { P = p, Index = idx})
.ToList()
.ForEach(pIndexPair => 
 {
      var infoSpot = LoadInfoSpot(pIndexPair.Index);
      pIndexPair.P.BackColor = string.IsNullOrEmpty(infospot) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
 });
```